# Rotation: Quaternion to matrix

Tags: opengl, rotation, quaternions

I am trying to display a 360 panorama using an IMU for head tracking.

Yaw works correctly but the roll and pitch are reverse. I also notice that the pitch contains some roll (and maybe vice-versa).

I am receiving (W, X, Y, Z) coordinate from the IMU that I am storing in an array as X, Y, Z, W.

The next step is converting the quaternion to a rotation matrix. I have looked at many examples, and can't seem to find anything wrong with the following code:

```
static GLfloat rotation[16];

// Quaternion (x, y, z, w)
static void quaternionToRotation(float* quaternion)
{
  // Normalize quaternion
  float magnitude = sqrt(quaternion[0] * quaternion[0] +
                         quaternion[1] * quaternion[1] + 
                         quaternion[2] * quaternion[2] + 
                         quaternion[3] * quaternion[3]); 
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    quaternion[i] /= magnitude;
  }

  double xx = quaternion[0] * quaternion[0], xy = quaternion[0] * quaternion[1],
         xz = quaternion[0] * quaternion[2], xw = quaternion[0] * quaternion[3];
  double yy = quaternion[1] * quaternion[1], yz = quaternion[1] * quaternion[2],
         yw = quaternion[1] * quaternion[3];
  double zz = quaternion[2] * quaternion[2], zw = quaternion[2] * quaternion[3];

  // Column major order
  rotation[0] = 1.0f - 2.0f * (yy + zz);
  rotation[1] = 2.0f * (xy - zw);
  rotation[2] = 2.0f * (xz + yw); 
  rotation[3] = 0; 

  rotation[4] = 2.0f * (xy + zw);
  rotation[5] = 1.0f - 2.0f * (xx + zz);
  rotation[6] = 2.0f * (yz - xw);
  rotation[7] = 0; 

  rotation[8] = 2.0f * (xz - yw);
  rotation[9] = 2.0f * (yz + xw);
  rotation[10] = 1.0f - 2.0f * (xx + yy);
  rotation[11] = 0; 

  rotation[12] = 0; 
  rotation[13] = 0; 
  rotation[14] = 0; 
  rotation[15] = 1; 
}
```

The rotation matrix is then used in the draw call as such:

```
static void draw()
{
  // Get IMU quaternion
  float* quaternion = tracker.getTrackingData();
  if (quaternion != NULL)
  {
    quaternionToRotation(quaternion);
  }

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glLoadIdentity();

  glPushMatrix();
  // TODO: Multiply initialRotation quaternion with IMU quaternion
  glMultMatrixf(initialRotation); // Initial rotation to point forward
  glMultMatrixf(rotation); // Rotation based on IMU

  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  gluSphere(quad, 0.1, 50, 50);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
  glPopMatrix();

  glFlush();
  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I tried to set all but one fields in the quaternion to 0, and I notice that they all work individually, except roll and pitch is swapped around. I tried swapping X and Y but this does not seem to help.

Any help would be really appreciated. Please let me know as well if you have any steps that can let me debug my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that the quaternion from `tracker.getTrackingData()` actually makes sense? Is your IMU properly calibrated? Seems like there could be a lot of other things beyond converting a quaternion to a matrix causing trouble.

Comment: I believe so, I will double check though. I have ran a sample application that displays an image of the IMU (as rotated) and it looks correct. I will double check that my code mimics that correctly, but I believe that works.

Comment: What other things can come to your mind (except calibration)? Maybe I can try to rule them out one by one.

Comment: I have been thinking about your comment. One thing that stands out is that if I set 2 out of 3 quaternions (x, y, z) to 0, yaw, roll and pitch work individually (except pitch and roll is switched). Turning them all of them on creates issue where roll has some pitch and vice versa.

Comment: I was thinking of issues related to the hardware mostly, bad data on an I2C bus or something like that (depending of course on how your IMU is actually connected). But I'm really just considering that because your quaternionToMatrix code all looks fine.

Comment: I am using an intersense inertiacube 4, it communicates via USB. I think the data looks sane. I a starting to wonder if my initialRotation is causing the issue. I am doing 2 rotations in a row, it might be introducing the problem (the initial rotation was to have the 360 panorama look forward instead of up in the sky).

Comment: Ah, that looks a bit more robust than the IMU's I'm used to so that's probably not the issue either. Could be the initial rotation then - what does it look like if you just perform the IMU rotation?

Comment: I just figured out the issue, I was rotating the sphere, not the camera, so I had to actually pass row-major instead of column major to solve my issue!